# To assign dynamic URL's

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT Language, I am trying to write code that assigns dynamic URL's to Photo field in my list. My list contains FirstName, LastName and Photo fields of all employees and Photos are in a folder ("file://folder/subfolder/LastName, FirstName.jpg). Based on FirstName and LastName appropriate photo should be dynamically added to Photo Field.

Code I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="udt:Photo">
<xsl:for-each select="dnnGridItem">
<xsl:value-of select="udt:LastName" />
<xsl:value-of select="udt:FirstName" />
</xsl:for-each>
<img border="0" alt="delete">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:text>file://folder/subfolder</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="file://foilder/subfoilder/?{LastName}, {FirstName}.jpg" />
    <xsl:text>.jpg</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
</xsl:template>
```

Can any one help me with XSL code.

Comment: Could you also provide a small (but significant) example of the XML file/data you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide any input data I can suggest my example. 
In my case required images are in path **D:/images** as below:

[image]

So to add images to HTML I am using next XSL file (**photo.xsl**) as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="html" /> 
    <xsl:template match="/Photo">
        <xsl:variable name="img.path" select="'file:///D:/images/'"/>
        <html>
            <body>                               
                <xsl:for-each select="dnnGridItem">
                    <xsl:variable name="img.name" select="concat(LastName, ', ', FirstName)"/>
                    <h2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$img.name"/>
                    </h2>
                    <img border="0" alt="delete">
                        <xsl:attribute name="src">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat($img.path, $img.name, '.jpg')"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </img>
                    <br/>            
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </body>
        </html>           
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then to take LastName and FirstName dynamically add `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="photo.xsl"?>`  to input XML file (**input.xml**) as below:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="photo.xsl"?>
<Photo>
    <dnnGridItem>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </dnnGridItem>
    <dnnGridItem>
        <FirstName>Kate</FirstName>
        <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
    </dnnGridItem>    
</Photo>
```

Result:

- Transformed result:

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Smith, John</h2>
            <img border="0" alt="delete" src="file:///D:/images/Smith, John.jpg"><br>
            <h2>Johnson, Kate</h2>
            <img border="0" alt="delete" src="file:///D:/images/Johnson, Kate.jpg"><br>
        </body>
    </html>
```

- Result when open XML(**input.xml**) file in browser:

[image]

NOTE! **input.xml** - in same folder with **photo.xsl**.

Hope it will help with your case.